# Get static methods with attribute and subscribe them to an event

Tags: c#, events, reflection

How would one get all the static methods that have a certain attribute applied to them through reflection, and then subscribe those methods to an event?

Class whose method is loaded through reflection:

```
public static class EventsAndStuff
{
    [DoStuffEvent]
    public static void OnDoStuff(object sender, DoStuffEventArgs e)
    {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Here is a possible place where the reflection would be done, to make things clear (at the beginning of `main()`)

```
public static class Program
{
    // event to subscribe to
    public static event DoStuffEventHandler DoStuff;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // reflection here
    }
}
```

When the loading program starts, how would I subscribe `OnDoStuff()` to an event `DoStuffEvent`, so that when `DoStuffEvent` is invoked, it would call OnDoStuff and any other static methods with a `DoStuffEventAttribute` applied?

I suspect this has to do with `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate()` but the MSDN documentation isn't particularly clear.

Most of the similar questions involve subscribing a non-reflection method to a reflection-loaded event. How could one do the reverse?

Comment: I don't think there is anything native for this. So you'd have to have like a superclass in constructor of which you'd reflect all methods and create relevant delegates. Because right now what you have is an instance signature so you can't do this on 'program loading' unless you already have those instances.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot the method (and class) were supposed to be static.

Comment: if they're static, then you can basically loop through all classes in an assembly and see which ones have the attribute applied, and then subscribe events. But you still need to have event source at that point (e.g. the other object/Rx etc.).

Comment: That's just it. Syntactically, how would this be done, knowing and having access to the event subscribed to?

Comment: well, i've been beat by @Erik, but my solution was basically what he had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic solution is to iterate through the classes in the assembly(-ies) that you want to search through and test the classes. Static classes are marked as sealed and abstract by the compiler, so you need to test for that. Then for each method, check if it's static and whether the attribute is present. Then create the delegate of the correct type and subscribe it to the event.

```
public class SubscriberAttribute : Attribute { }

static class TestClass
{
    [SubscriberAttribute]
    static void Method(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method called as expected.");
    }

    static void Nonsubscribed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Wrong method called!");
    }
}

class MethodSubscriber
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ms = new MethodSubscriber();

        ms.SubscribeToEvent(typeof(MethodSubscriber).Assembly);
    }

    public event EventHandler TestEvent;

    void SubscribeToEvent(Assembly assembly)
    {
        foreach (var type in assembly.GetTypes())
        {
            // Test for a static class
            if (type.IsSealed == false) continue;
            if (type.IsClass == false) continue;

            // Check each method for the attribute.
            foreach (var method in type.GetRuntimeMethods())
            {
                // Make sure the method is static
                if (method.IsStatic == false) continue;

                // Test for presence of the attribute
                var attribute = method.GetCustomAttribute<SubscriberAttribute>();

                if (attribute == null)
                    continue;

                var del = (EventHandler)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(EventHandler));

                TestEvent += del;
            }
        }

        TestEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

The `CreateDelegate` method will throw an exception if the method's signature doesn't match the delegate type, so you may want to put in some sort of handling for that case. You could avoid the exception by reflecting over the method parameters and seeing if they match the types expected by the event.